# In linux kernel level,how to read and write a sector of hard

Tags: linux, kernel

For some reasons, I need to read and write a sector of hard disk in my module.

I want to read and write a sector by programming in the kernel level

My linux kernel version is 3.13.0.

Is there anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you can do in your module.
If you are working on the shell, you may be able to use the `dd` command.

`dd if=/dev/sda of=outfile`

If you cannot use user-space commands, you may have to work on the disk block device directly.
You need to open the device using `open(2)` system call (see `man 2 open` for details).

```
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/sda", FLAGS);
```

After that you can perform read commands (man 2 read) to read from the device.

`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`

You can also send commands to the device using IOCTLs:

`int ioctl(int d, int request, ...);`

Using these calls you should be flexible enough to do whatever you want to do with your disk.

Comment: This is not the answer what I want.I want to read and write a sector by programming in the kernel level.